# Como fazer aceitar 0 e valores negativos em atributo decimal usando DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotation, model-validation

Tenho uma classe com valores **decimais** que podem receber um valor de **-10.00 a 10.00** (**inclusive 0**), no Sql Server o valor equivalente é um **numeric(5,2)**. O problema é que ao criar minha classe **MetaData**, mesmo especificando o **range** a validação não tem funcionado.

Obs: Em minha **View** está tudo certo, estou usando o **ValidationMessageFor**.

Meu código (Trecho):

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "VALIDACAO_REQUERIDO", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
[Range(-10.00, 10.00, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve estar entre {1} e {2}")]
public decimal Valor;
```

Comment: Sem código e sem mais detalhes do problema fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Acabei de fazer uma edição @bigown, foi mal...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Poste por favor o trecho da sua *View*, o `packages.config` e o `web.config`. Fiz um projeto com instalação padrão e funcionou de primeira usando seu código.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "-10", "10")]
```